# Is there a function to add non null columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 7],
'col2': [4, 5, np.nan, 9, 5]})
```

I want sum of null values (col1, col2) to be null How it can be achieved?

```
d['SUM' ]=d[[ ' col1' , 'col2' ]]. sum (axis=1)
d
```

With the sum function I got sum of null values as
'O'

```
COl1 col2 SUM
0 1.0 4.0 5.0
1 NaN 5.0 5.0
NaN NaN 0.0
3 4.0 9.0 13.0
4 7.0 5.0 12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `mask` according to your rule:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']

df['SUM'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1).mask(df[cols].isna().all(1))
```

output:

```
   col1  col2   SUM
0   1.0   4.0   5.0
1   NaN   5.0   5.0
2   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   4.0   9.0  13.0
4   7.0   5.0  12.0
```

If you want any NaN to yield NaN:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df['SUM'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1, skipna=False)
```

output:

```
   col1  col2   SUM
0   1.0   4.0   5.0
1   NaN   5.0   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   4.0   9.0  13.0
4   7.0   5.0  12.0
```